# How to resolve TypeError while running ProfileReport using pandas_profiling?

Tags: python, typeerror, pandas-profiling

I am working with the below specifications

Python version = 3.8.5
Pandas version = 1.2.4

While running ProfileReport of pandas_profiling on jupyter notebook getting the below error.

`TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'`

is there any solution to this problem apart from downgrading to an older version?

Answer (score 3):

Install directly from repo:

```
pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip

import pandas_profiling as pdpf
```

Comment: It gave an error -
Failed to build bottleneck
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: **Works in Google Colab** :) Where Python version is 3.7.13 (on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS).